# best practice for accessing context information for logging

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to the web development.

For simplicity, let's assume there's one Textfield for setting the number of products (context information), and one button for submission (components that want to access the context information).
I'd like to log the timestamp and the number of products on the button click.
The button should be able to access the information from Textfield.

What is the best way to achieve this?
(in case it matters, I'm using google tag manager & their datalayer for logging)

The above example is simple, but in the real application, the components are multi-level nested, and the buttons are everywhere.

If I use `useContext()` or `useForm()`, it re-renders the components, but I don't really need re-rendering because it's only for logging.
Also it doesn't look good to make the components (e.g., button) dependent on the information they don't actually need for their functionality other than logging.

Comment: Do you think jotai will solve the problem, it reduces the re-rendering problems https://jotai.org/

Comment: Welcome, let me know if you are facing problems setting it up